# How to install cocos-2d templates in Xcode 5?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

When i am trying to execute following command from Terminal in Maverick os(Xcode 5) to install templates of cocos2d 3.0 rc-1, I am getting following message.

-bash: install.sh: command not found

What could be the reason ?
Please help by giving some meaningful comments/hint...

Answer (score 8):

1. Download [Latest Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/download/).
2. Open the terminal (Don't type anything).
3. Drag the install file (install-templates.sh/install.sh) into the terminal.
4. Finally press enter only.

Now,you check the Xcode->New Project there you get cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

To install cocos2d to Xcode on Mavericks, in terminal type in the following commands. Also you should move the cocos2d folder to your desktop just for simplicity.

```
cd ~\Desktop\[Cocos2d Folder];
sudo install.sh //I think you are missing the 'sudo'
```

Then enter in your password when you are prompted. Text will not show up even if you are typing. After terminal finishes you can open up you xcode and you should see a cocos2d template option on the left navigation bar.

Tutorial: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/ad-hoc-beta-testing/75910-how-to-install-cocos2d-in-xcode.html

Cocos2d: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Cocos2d installer that they provide on there website

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Cocos2D-3.0.dmg

The link will start the download and them install the dmg, the program takes care of the rest :D

If you'd like to read up on it go to http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download/ and look at the section marked 1)